# Help updating object record from VF page

Tags: apex, class, update

i created a PageBlockTable, there is  a button that open a popup window, inside the window I successfully display details from the child object. In this popup there is a button 'Save and close' for some reason i am able to insert a new value but I am not able to update the value from the inputext field. I would like to know if i  am doing something wrong

Below is the code, i will appreciate any help.

VF page popUp code:

```
<apex:column >  

   <apex:commandButton value="Resolve" action="{!showPopup3}" rerender="popup3"> 
        <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedOSO}" name="SelectedOSO" value="{!d.Detail}"/>
    </apex:commandButton>

 <!-- popup -->
   <apex:outputPanel id="popup3">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!PopUpVisible3}">
           Resolution for {!d.Detail}<br/><br/><br/>   

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SODetails}" var="t">


          <apex:column headerValue="id" >

            <apex:outputField value="{!t.id}"/>
          </apex:column>  

             <apex:column headerValue="NRCode" >

            <apex:outputField value="{!t.NRProduct_Display__c}"/>
        </apex:column>

              <apex:column headerValue="Amazon Received" >

            <apex:inputField value="{!t.Amazon_Received__c}"/> //this is the value to update

          </apex:column>           

    <apex:column >
    <apex:commandButton value="Save and Close" action="{!HidePopUp3()}" rerender="popup3" />    
     </apex:column>
              </apex:pageBlockTable>                                  


        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

   <!---end popup-->
```

here is the class:

```
     public String ShipmentId{ get{ return   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); } }


  public transient String SelectedOSO {get; set; }
  public List<SO_Detail__c> SODetails {get; set;}  
  public Boolean PopUpVisible3{ get; set; }

public void ShowPopUp3(){ 
    PopUpVisible3 = true; 
    PopulateRelated3();
}
public void HidePopUp3(){ 

    update SODetails;
    PopulateRelated3();
    PopUpVisible3 = false; 
}


    public void PopulateRelated3(){

    SODetails=[select id, Name, UPC__c, Display_1__c, NRProducts__c, Issue__c, 
    Amazon_Received__c,  NRProduct_Display__c  from SO_Detail__c where    SO_Detail__c.Outbound_Sales_Order__r.id=:ShipmentId AND Name = :SelectedOSO  ]; 

    }
```

Comment: It looks like "Save and Close" should persist the changes but as `SelectedOSO` is transient I don't see how the `SODetails` list would be anything but empty after that. But that isn't the problem you report...

Comment: Keith, yeah it is weird... it doesn't make sense I used this code before and it worked but no in this case. I had to change the approach, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that command buttons inside of main panels that are not rendered on page load do not actually perform any request back to the controller once the section is rendered.

To get around this when it occurs, I render the section on page load and use query or something similar to hide the section then show it later. This way the button works properly when the section is displayed.